# No KeyValueTextInputFormat (new MapReduce API) in Hadoop 0.20.*

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I just set up a single node cluster Hadoop (pseudo distributed mode) with Hadoop 0.20.205 and ran some job written in the new MapReduce API.

I got some no Class found error on KeyValueTextInputForma class (org.apache.hadoop.**mapreduce**.lib.input.KeyValueTextInputFormat) and then realized that hadoop 0.20.205 (not CDH distribution) doesn't seem to support the exact same MapReduce API as CDH3. What would be alternative class for KeyValueTextInputFormat for the new API in 0.20.205?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I have to use TextInputFormat and split the value part myself.

Comment: Or you can port KeyValueTextInputFormat from 0.22 branch.